# Horizontal line marking left side of a tabularx table is moved to the right

Tags: tabularx

The problem is hard to explain, so I'll paste screenshot instead:

[image]

You can clearly see there is some problem with this table: somehow horizontal lines separating rows are going outside the table. Moreover, string located in second row (SourceNodeId) is not centered, but moved slightly to the left.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \newcommand{\tabularxmulticolumnleft}[3] 
        {\multicolumn{#1}
                     {>{\raggedright\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}#2}
                     {#3}}
    \newcommand{\tabularxmulticolumncentered}[3] 
        {\multicolumn{#1}
                     {>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}#2}
                     {#3}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{16}{X}  }
        \hline
        \tabularxmulticolumnleft{4}{|X}{0} & \tabularxmulticolumnleft{4}{|X}{3} & \tabularxmulticolumnleft{4}{|X}{7} &\tabularxmulticolumnleft{4}{|X|}{11} \\
        \hline
        \tabularxmulticolumncentered{16}{|X|}{SourceNodeId} \\
        \hline
        \tabularxmulticolumncentered{4}{|X}{MessageType} & \tabularxmulticolumncentered{4}{|X}{RetransmissionId} & \tabularxmulticolumncentered{1}{|X}{ExpectAck} &
        \tabularxmulticolumncentered{7}{|X|}{IV}\\
        \hline
        \tabularxmulticolumncentered{9}{|X}{IV} & \tabularxmulticolumncentered{4}{|X}{PayloadSize} & \tabularxmulticolumncentered{3}{|X|}{Payload}\\
        \hline
        \tabularxmulticolumncentered{16}{|X|}{Payload}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{table:dataframe_header}
\end{table}
```

Do you see what could be a problem here?

PS: structure of the table is intentional. I wanted to have fixed-size columns, all with equal width. Table represents byte array, it is meant to show what information is located in each fragment. Here is an example of such table: [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6747#section-2.2)

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document that we can test as it is.

Comment: please post a small error free document that produces the output shown. If I guess a preamble  I get `! Package array Error: >{..} at wrong position: token ignored.
`

Comment: your hsize adjustment `\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth` looks wrong, if you span 2 columns you need to subtract the arrayrulewidth from the text width to make room for the rule, not add it, but without an error free test file hard to say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (Observe that I've replaced `ExpectAck` with `I` because `ExpectAck` simply cannot fit in a narrow column.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
% idea for following code comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566577/5001
\newcommand\newhsize[1]{\hsize=\dimexpr #1\hsize
           +#1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep
           +#1\arrayrulewidth-\arrayrulewidth \relax}
\newcommand{\mcL}[2]{ \multicolumn{#1}{ >{\newhsize{#1}}L|}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mcC}[2]{ \multicolumn{#1}{ >{\newhsize{#1}}C|}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mcLL}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{|>{\newhsize{#1}}L|}{#2}} % "|" at LHS
\newcommand{\mcCC}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{|>{\newhsize{#1}}C|}{#2}} % "|" at LHS
%% (LHS: left-hand side)

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{16}{X} |}
        \hline
        \mcLL{4}{0} & \mcL{4}{3} & \mcL{4}{7} & \mcL{4}{11} \\
        \hline
        \mcCC{16}{SourceNodeId} \\
        \hline
        \mcCC{4}{MessageType} & \mcC{4}{RetransmissionId} & \mcC{1}{I} & \mcC{7}{IV}\\
        \hline
        \mcCC{9}{IV} & \mcC{4}{PayloadSize} & \mcC{3}{Payload}\\
        \hline
        \mcCC{16}{Payload}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly